# Multiple folders in one share?

Tags: windows, network-share

I have a folder layout like this (simplified):

```
d:\Share1\A
d:\Share1\B
d:\Share1\C

e:\Share2\D
e:\Share2\E
e:\Share2\F
```

The two main folders are shared. Is it possible to create a single share that contains both subfolders?

```
\\SERVER\Share\A
\\SERVER\Share\B
\\SERVER\Share\C
\\SERVER\Share\D
\\SERVER\Share\E
...
```

I can't use junctions because the subfolders change a lot. Is there any other way to get this done? Im using Win2003 R2, if there is a solution for 2008 or 2008 R2 i can upgrade...

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... I don't use DFS a lot but I'm thinking it would do the job. Create a DFS root and add links to all the shares. Then all of the shares should be available via the DFS root. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yeah, DFS will do this and no need to upgrade, it works in 2003.

Comment: +1 for DFS, this is how I'd solve this